# Does TensorFlowJS require HTML? Or can I upload images and video from my PC?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create an Object classifier discord bot that runs on Discord.js, Everything is going relatively smooth, but I'm running into this error:

`pixels passed to tf.browser.frompixels() cannot be null`

As far as I understand, this is because I'm using images from my computer and not HTML images with the "`<img>`" tag.

So I was wondering if I'm wrong and there's a way around this or is this just impossible?

***NOTE:*** I'm using COCO-SSD as a pre-trained model

Answer (score 0):

you can use the trained model to detect object from videos or images from your computer. I've done a whole project on it, you can check it out right [here](https://github.com/MohammedAhmed49/object-detection).

or follow this steps.
1- Load the model

```
const coco = require('@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd')

const loadModel =async()=>{
    try{
        const model = await coco.load()
        return model
    }catch(err){
        console.log("there was an error loading the model trying re-loading attempt...")
        return 0;
    }
}

module.exports = loadModel
```

2- read the image and turn and convert it so it can be read by the model.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')

ImageName = '../VidUploads/imageUp-1589491328827.jpg'

const readImage = (path)=>{
    const buffer = fs.readFileSync(path)
    try { 
      const pixels =tf.node.decodeImage(new Uint8Array(buffer),3)
      console.log(`image shape ${pixels.shape}`)
      return pixels 
    }catch(err){
      console.log(`something went wrong while converting the image to tensor`)
      return -1 
    }
   
   
}
```

3- use the model

```
const imagePrediction =async(model , image)=>{

           return ( await model.detect(image))    
}
```

***Note:*** the `imagePrediction` takes the model from step 2 and the image from step 1 as inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I'm getting this error when I try to run index.js (Even though i have installed tfjs-node and did require(@tensorflow/tfjs-node)): `Error: The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found at path:`

Comment: I also get this error: `something went wrong while converting the image to tensor
(node:29180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: model.detect is not a function`